# Why is so much difference in the size of Firefox and Safari setups for Windows?

Tags: firefox, browser, safari

Just wondering, one is 8MB (Mozilla Firefox) and the other is 28MB (Apple Safari).

**Why is there so much difference in the size of these browsers?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple application bundles a lot of software which is meant to support other Apple products such as the iPhone and iTunes. 
If you break the installation file up using [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract), you can see the bloat.

Among the products that Apple installs are the very annoying Apple Software Update and Bonjour. In addition, it includes two versions in the installation file: both 32-bits and 64-bits.

Mozilla Firefox installs just one 32-bits browser, and with a minimal number of add-ons. It has no aspirations to being a platform. It's just a browser.

This is one of the reasons that I haven't considered Safari as a browser alternative to Firefox.

Comment: XULRunner (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner) indicates aspirations to become a platform, even if it's handled poorly. And Firefox is a superset of that!

Comment: @Anonymous: Small aspirations when compared to Apple.